# If I leave an else empty , it falses my posts that are counting on "posts_per_page" on Wordpress, how to correct that?

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements

I have a condition that says **:**

if the posts are superiors of `today -> show`

`else -> //do nothing`, I leave empty and then my posts disappear if there are inferiors of today.

But the problem is that I have `10` posts per page but because of this empty else I have only `7` who appear for example.

So how can I say in the empty else to display the following posts which are still valid ?

**Here's my code :**

```
<?php if (get_field('fin_de_levenement')){ ?>
<?php $now = time();
$date_one_timestamp = strtotime(get_field('fin_de_levenement', false, false));
if ($now < $date_one_timestamp ) { ?>
<div>my content</div>
<?php } else {
// do nothing 
} ?>
```

Thank you !

Comment: If the else is doing nothing remove it `if( $now < $date_one_timestamp ) { //Do Something }` is enough.

Comment: You should filter invalid results as part of your pagination routine and not after you've paginated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove your else statement.

```
<?php if (get_field('fin_de_levenement')){ ?>
<?php $now = time();
$date_one_timestamp = strtotime(get_field('fin_de_levenement', false, false));
if ($now < $date_one_timestamp ) { ?>
<div>my content</div>
<?php }
```